# Bootstrap 4 не поддерживает gliphicons, как решить проблему?

Tags: bootstrap

Заводя новый проект, было принято использовать bootstrap 4 alfa.
В проект был притянут код который использовал bootstrap 3, и соответсвеено все gliphicon перестали отображаться. Как решить проблему чтобы в bootstrap 4 отображались иконки из bootstrap3?

Comment: Опечатка здесь и частично в ответе. Нужно `glyphicons` через `y`. http://glyphicons.com/

Answer (score 2):

1. Скачайте bootstrap 3 из официального репозитория.
2. Зайдите в папку `dist` и скопируйте папку `fonts` себе в корень проекта или куда пожелаете.
3. Зайдите в папку `less` и найдите файл `glyphicons.less`
4. Так как я использую `sass` я создал файл `_fonts.scss` и написал в него

следующий код:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')
    format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2')
    format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')
    format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')
    format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular')
    format('svg');
}
```

после этого вставил содержимое файла `glyphicons.less` , удалив у него подключение шрифтов - вот этот кусок кода:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
 src: url('@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.eot');
 src: url('@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.woff') format('woff'),
      url('@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.svg#@{icon-font-svg-id}') format('svg');
}
```

все остальное оставил как было.

5. Подключил получившейся файл `fonts.scss` в файл сборки, запустил компиляцию в моем случае это сделал `compass`